# lua call GetTickCount breakdown

Tags: lua

I use lua call windows API occur breakdown! I can't understand, help!
platform:win7, lua5.1forwindows

```
<i>require "alien"

--alien.load("Dll.dll")
--print(alien.defalt)
--[[
def = alien.load("msvcrt.dll")
def.puts:types("int", "string")
def.puts("foo")

scanf = def.scanf
scanf:types("int", "string", "ref int", "ref double")
_, x, y = scanf("%i%lf", 0, 0)
print(x, y)
--]]

local Kernel32 = alien.load('kernel32.dll')
GetTickCount = Kernel32.GetTickCount
GetTickCount:types{ret = "ulong", "void", abi = "stdcall"}
local c = GetTickCount(nil)</i>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to be more precise with your question. You are not likely to get help if you form your question like this. Post all relevant code and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've over-complicated your code. this snippet prints the current tick count:

```
require "alien"

local kernel = alien.load("kernel32.dll")
local ticks = kernel.GetTickCount
ticks:types({ret="ulong"})
print(ticks())
```